# Multiple RunWith Statements in jUnit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I write unit test and want to use `JUnitParamsRunner` and `MockitoJUnitRunner` for one test class.

Unfortunately, the following does not work:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class DatabaseModelTest {
  // some tests
}
```

Is there a way to use both, Mockito and JUnitParams in one test class?

Comment: Have a look: https://code.google.com/p/junitparams/wiki/MergingWithOtherRunners

Comment: There's a nice example here also: http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/coding/1077/runwith-junit4-with-both-springjunit4classrunner-and-parameterized/

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You cannot do this because according to spec you cannot put the same annotation twice on the same annotated element.

So, what is the solution? The solution is to put only one `@RunWith()` with runner you cannot stand without and replace other one with something else. In your case I guess you will remove `MockitoJUnitRunner` and do programatically what it does.

In fact the only thing it does it runs:

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(test);
```

in the beginning of test case. So, the simplest solution is to put this code into `setUp()` method:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

I am not sure, but *probably* you should avoid multiple call of this method using flag:

```
private boolean mockInitialized = false;
@Before
public void setUp() {
    if (!mockInitialized) {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockInitialized = true;  
    }
}
```

However better, reusable solution may be implemented with JUnt's rules.

```
public class MockitoRule extends TestWatcher {
    private boolean mockInitialized = false;

    @Override
    protected void starting(Description d) {
        if (!mockInitialized) {
            MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
            mockInitialized = true;  
        }
    }
}
```

Now just add the following line to your test class:

```
@Rule public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
```

and you can run this test case with any runner you want.

Comment: The check for `mockInitialized` is wrong. You want to have a fresh mock for every tetst.

Comment: @BetaRide, it depends on your needs. Sometimes you want to initialize mock every time, sometimes not.

Comment: If you want to set up once per class file you can use BeforeClass instead of Before, which will be invoked once and only once per test file.

Answer (score 60):

As of JUnit 4.7 and Mockito 1.10.17, this functionality is built in; there is an [`org.mockito.junit.MockitoRule`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/junit/MockitoRule.html) class. You can simply import it and add the line

```
@Rule public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
```

to your test class.

Comment: For older versions of Mockito (down to 1.10.5 it seems), you have to use: `@Rule public MockitoJUnitRule mockito = new MockitoJUnitRule(this);`

Comment: `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` is very slow to create mocks. The most efficient way is to use the @Runwith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)

Comment: But as the OP mentioned, you cannot use two @RunWith statements and he needed to use another one.

Answer (score 19):

This solution works for every possible runner, not just this mockito example. For example; for Spring, just change the runner classes and add necessary annotations.

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class DatabaseModelTest {

    @Test
    public void subRunner() throws Exception {
        JUnitCore.runClasses(TestMockitoJUnitRunner.class);
    }

    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
    public static class TestMockitoJUnitRunner {
    }
}
```

`DatabaseModelTest` will be run by JUnit. `TestMockitoJUnitRunner` depends on it (by logic) and it will be run *inside* of the main in a `@Test` method, during the call `JUnitCore.runClasses(TestMockitoJUnitRunner.class)`. This method ensures the main runner is started correctly before the `static class TestMockitoJUnitRunner` sub-runner runs, effectively implementing multiple nested `@RunWith` annotations with dependent test classes.

Also on https://bekce.github.io/junit-multiple-runwith-dependent-tests

Comment: By calling `JUnitCore.runClasses()` without inspecting the result, you risk masking the errors from the inner test. `assert(JUnitCore.runClasses(TestMockitoJUnitRunner.class).wasSuccessful());` will at least report the error to you

Answer (score 8):

Since the release of PowerMock 1.6, you can do it as easily as

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class DatabaseModelTest {
  // some tests
}
```

Explained here https://blog.jayway.com/2014/11/29/using-another-junit-runner-with-powermock/

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was trying to Mock some method in spring bean and

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(test);
```

doesn't works. Instead you have to define that bean to constructed using mock method inside your xml file like following.

```
...
<bean id="classWantedToBeMocked" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="com.fullpath.ClassWantedToBeMocked" />
</bean>
...
```

and add that bean with autowired inside your test class like following.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="file:springconfig.xml")
public class TestClass {
    ...
    @Autowired
    private ClassWantedToBeMocked classWantedToBeMocked;
    ...
    when(classWantedToBeMocked.methodWantedToBeMocked()).thenReturn(...);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this link https://bekce.github.io/junit-multiple-runwith-dependent-tests/
using this approach i combined a @RunWith(Parameterized.class) - outer runner - with @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) - inner runner. The only tweak i had to add was to make my member variables in the outer class/runner static in order to make them accessible for the inner/nested runner/class. gook luck and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to run **SWTBotJunit4ClassRunner** and **org.junit.runners.Parameterized** at the same time, I have parametric tests and I want to screenshots when the SWT test fails (the screenshot feature is provided by the **SWTBotJunit4ClassRunner**). @bekce's answer is great and first wanted go that route but it was either quirky passing through the arguments. Or doing the parametrized in the subclass and loosing the information what exact tests passed/failed and have only the last screenshot (as the screenshot names get the name from the test itself). So either way it was bit messy.

In my case the **SWTBotJunit4ClassRunner** is simple enough, so I cloned the source-code of the class, gave it my own name **ParametrizedScreenshotRunner** and where original was extending the **TestRunner**, my class is extending the **Parameterized** class so in essence I can use my own runner instead of the previous two. Boiled down my own runner extends on top of Parameterized runner while implementing the screenshot feature on top of it, now my test use this "hybrid" runner and all the tests work as expected straight away (no need to change anything inside the tests).

This is how it looks like (for sake of brevity I removed all the comments from the listing):

```
package mySwtTests;

import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.eclipse.swtbot.swt.finder.junit.ScreenshotCaptureListener;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener;
import org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier;

public class ParametrizedScreenshotRunner extends TestRu Parameterized {

    public ParametrizedScreenshotRunner(Class<?> klass) throws Throwable {
        super(klass);
    }

    public void run(RunNotifier notifier) {
        RunListener failureSpy = new ScreenshotCaptureListener();
        notifier.removeListener(failureSpy); // remove existing listeners that could be added by suite or class runners
        notifier.addListener(failureSpy);
        try {
            super.run(notifier);
        } finally {
            notifier.removeListener(failureSpy);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there are no solution in JUnit 4 it is possible to register multiple extensions in JUnit 5:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@ExtendWith(AnotherExtension.class)
public class MyTest {
  // some tests
}
```

Note that `JUnitParams` framework is built into JUnit 5.

Answer (score -15):

You can also try this:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class AbstractTestClass {
  // some tests
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class DatabaseModelTest extends AbstractTestClass {
  // some tests
}
```

Comment: This won't work, only the sub-class annotation will be processed.

Comment: does not work - only MockitoJUnitRunner annotation will be taken into account