# how to merge these two RunWith runners?

Tags: junit-runner

I have created two Runners both of whom are inherited from BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.
One is to filter some tests based on conditions. The other is to run test multiple methods concurrently. I want to apply both these runner so that the tests are run based on conditions and concurrently.

The problem is we cannot annotate multiple @RunWith to the same tests, according to [Multiple RunWith Statements in jUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431427/multiple-runwith-statements-in-junit).

my question is since both these two runners are inherited from the same base class BlockJUnit4ClassRunner, can I combine these two runners to be one so that RunWith this runner, I can run test methods based on conditions and using concurrent way? And How to do that?

Here are the two runners I created:

1) This runner runs test methods based on some conditions defined in FunctionalTestFilter:

```
public class FilterRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

     public FilterRunner(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        super(clazz);
        Filter f = new FunctionalTestFilter();
        try {
            f.apply(this);
        } catch (NoTestsRemainException ex) {
           System.out.println("Warning! No method run in " + clazz.getName());
        }
    }
```

2) This runner runs test methods concurrently using multi-threading:

```
public static class ConcurrentJunitMethodRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {
      public ConcurrentJunitMethodRunner(final Class<?> testclass) throws InitializationError {
          super(testclass);
          setScheduler(new RunnerScheduler() {
              ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
              CompletionService<Void> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Void>(executorService);
              Queue<Future<Void>> tasks = new LinkedList<Future<Void>>();

              @Override
              public void schedule(Runnable childStatement) {
                  tasks.offer(completionService.submit(childStatement, null));
              }

              @Override
              public void finished() {
                  try {
                      while (!tasks.isEmpty())
                          tasks.remove(completionService.take());
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                  } finally {
                      while (!tasks.isEmpty())
                          tasks.poll().cancel(true);
                      executorService.shutdownNow();
                  }
              }
          });
      }
  }
```