# Multiple runwith for a junit test class

Tags: spring, junit, annotations

Does any one know how to tackle this.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@RunWith(Parametrized.class)

@ContextConfiguration("/META-INF/blah-spring-test.xml")
public class BlahTest
..
```

so i want to have a spring nature test and at the same time want to have it parameterized to avoid code duplication ...

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431427/multiple-runwith-statements-in-junit.

Comment: I would suggest this is not exactly a duplicate as the runners are different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use two runners as it noted in the commented post. You should use the `Parameterized` runner as use Spring's [TestContextManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/test/context/TestContextManager.html) to load the Spring context.

```
@Before 
public void before() throws Exception {
  new TestContextManager(getClass()).prepareTestInstance(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring Framework 4.2, JUnit-based integration tests can now be executed with *JUnit rules* instead of the `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`. This allows Spring-based integration tests to be run with alternative runners like JUnit’s `Parameterized` or third-party runners such as the `MockitoJUnitRunner`. See more details on [spring doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-junit4-rules).

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [John B's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27237154/2812189) using [`TestContextManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestContextManager.html), one can also call [`beforeTestMethod()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestContextManager.html#beforeTestMethod-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Method-) and [`afterTestMethod()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/TestContextManager.html#afterTestMethod-java.lang.Object-java.lang.reflect.Method-java.lang.Throwable-) on it to better simulate [`SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/junit4/SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.html)'s behaviour (for instance loading database with [`@Sql`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/jdbc/Sql.html)).

These methods require a [`Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) parameter, so one can for instance take advantage of JUnit4's [`TestName`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.13/org/junit/rules/TestName.html) rule to get the current test method's name and then retrieving it by reflection.

```java
private static TestContextManager springTestContext
  = new TestContextManager(BlahTest.class);

@Rule
public TestName testName = new TestName();

@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
  springTestContext.prepareTestInstance(this);
  springTestContext.beforeTestMethod(this,
    getClass().getMethod(testName.getMethodName()));
}

@After
public void after() throws Exception {
  springTestContext.afterTestMethod(this,
    getClass().getMethod(testName.getMethodName()), null);
}
```