# How to use Mockito stubs in a JUnitParams parameter provider?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junitparams

I am trying to learn JUnit. Working on a particular problem I decided to use JUnitParams parameter providers. Each set of parameters for a test method I'm writing should contain two input values and a list against which results of a method call would be tested:

```
private static final Object[] getConstraints() {
    return new Object[]{
            new Object[]{15, Equipment.WHITEBOARD, Arrays.asList(new Classroom[]{classroomA, classroomB})},
            new Object[]{15, Equipment.PROJECTOR, Arrays.asList(new Classroom[]{classroomB})},
            new Object[]{15, Equipment.MICROPHONE, Arrays.asList(new Classroom[]{classroomA})},
            new Object[]{30, Equipment.WHITEBOARD, Arrays.asList(new Classroom[]{classroomB})},
            new Object[]{30, Equipment.PROJECTOR, Arrays.asList(new Classroom[]{classroomB})},
            new Object[]{30, Equipment.MICROPHONE, Arrays.asList(new Classroom[]{})},
            new Object[]{45, Equipment.WHITEBOARD, Arrays.asList(new Classroom[]{})},
            new Object[]{45, Equipment.PROJECTOR, Arrays.asList(new Classroom[]{})},
            new Object[]{45, Equipment.MICROPHONE, Arrays.asList(new Classroom[]{})},
    };
}
```

`classroomA` and `classroomB` are actually Mockito stubs prepared before each test execution:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    classroomA = mock(Classroom.class);
    classroomB = mock(Classroom.class);
    classrooms = Arrays.asList(new Classroom[]{classroomA, classroomB});

    when(classroomA.getName()).thenReturn("A");
    when(classroomA.getCapacity()).thenReturn(20);
    when(classroomA.getEquipment()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(new Equipment[]{Equipment.WHITEBOARD, Equipment.MICROPHONE}));

    when(classroomB.getName()).thenReturn("B");
    when(classroomB.getCapacity()).thenReturn(40);
    when(classroomB.getEquipment()).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(new Equipment[]{Equipment.WHITEBOARD, Equipment.PROJECTOR}));

    bookingSystem = new BookingSystem(classrooms);
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to use aforementioned lists of `Classroom` objects:

```
@Test
@Parameters(method = "getConstraints")
public void shouldBookClassroomMeetingConstraints(int capacity, Equipment equipment, List<Classroom>
        suitableClassrooms) {
    Assert.assertTrue("Should book a classroom that has a minimum capacity of " + capacity + " and has " +
            equipment,
            suitableClassrooms.contains(bookingSystem.book(capacity, equipment, ANY_DAY_OF_WEEK, ANY_HOUR)));
}
```

Debugging shows that during the first run `suitableClassrooms` contains 2 objects, but further inspection shows that all elements are null - the stubs I prepared are not there. Obviously, the tests don't pass or fail where they should pass or fail.

Is there a limitation on using JUnitParams with Mockito or am I using them wrong? What is the right way to use them?

It is also possible that this is a wrong technique of unit testing. If this is the case, what is the proper way of writing a test that verifies if the result of a method call is in a given array?

Comment: What is your problem? Exception?

Comment: My problem is that `suitableClassrooms.contains(...)` method always returns false because `suitableClassrooms` has only null elements. Mock stubs aren't in the list for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You test doesn't work because `JUnitParamsRunner` runner collects parameters for test (i.e. invokes `getConstraints` method) before invocation of `@Before` methods and even before `@BeforeClass`. So `classroomA` and `classroomB` are null at that moment. That is why `suitableClassrooms` consists of null elements.

The solution is to initialize `classroomA` and `classroomB` in the `getConstraints()` method.

Also I believe you can get rid of mockito here. `Classroom` looks like POJO and it's not necessary to mock POJOs. In such case you just need to create `Classroom` instance and fill it with necessary data.

Comment: You are correct. I initialized stubs at their declaration: `private static Classroom classroomA = mock(Classroom.class);` and now `suitableClassrooms` contains the stubs and my tests pass. As for POJOs, I'm trying to mock everything except SUTs right now as an exercise.

Answer (score -2):

You need to let the class know that you are running the test cases with Mockito. add below at the class level and it should work.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Comment: I cannot do that because my test class is already annotated with `@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)`. This problem was discussed at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431427/multiple-runwith-statements-in-junit