# How to Load @ContextConfiguration for a class other than SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I'm using this API I found online which suits exactly my purpose, but it uses its own runner and doesn't allow me to use Spring's own, which leads to plethora of problems. How do I load a context in that file?

I want to load some beans related to DAO btw, is that possible without @ContextConfiguration?

Comment: you could post your code that it is not working , otherwise you ll not get so helpful answers. Anyway you could wire the Context Manually in your Before Tests method like [here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-hello-world-example/)

Comment: Take some time and [read the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-junit4-rules).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431427/multiple-runwith-statements-in-junit for some ideas. Particularly, seeing what this API's runner actually does - you might be able to do all its work by calling methods in @BeforeClass instead; leaving you free to use Spring's runner.
Or have a look at JUnit5, which I've heard takes a different approach; effectively allowing multiple runners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in comments: instead of using the Spring JUnit runner, you can [use JUnit 4 Rules with the `@Rule` / `@ClassRule` annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#testcontext-junit4-rules). 
Awkwardly, you have to use both a class level and a method level rule, to get the full functionality:

```
@ClassRule
public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

@Rule
public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();
```