# What's the difference between @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) and @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)? When to use it appropriately?

Tags: java, junit, mockito

What's the difference between `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` and `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`? When to use it appropriately?

Answer (score 5):

### MockitoJUnitRunner

- specific for use with the Mockito test framework
- the Mockito framework helps with mocking dependencies when you want to focus your tests on a single class and avoid invoking methods on dependencies (instead invokes a mock/dummy that is easily configured).
- Above is what mockito is used for, but for more on this runner specifically - from the docs: "keeps tests clean and improves debugging experience". "Runner is completely optional - there are other ways you can get @Mock working". Source - https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.8/org/mockito/junit/MockitoJUnitRunner.html

### SpringJunit4ClassRunner

- specific for use with the spring framework
- used for integration tests when it is required to load the spring context (create spring beans, perform dependency injection, etc).
- In integration tests you may not do as much mocking of dependencies but you can do both in the same test.
- Integration tests are useful when you would like to test loading the spring context or perhaps test from the service/high level all the way down to lower levels like data access with a single test.

In some cases you may want to use both - like an integration test where you would also like to mock some dependencies (perhaps they make remote calls).  Unfortunately you can't use two @RunWiths but this is a good post about that - [Multiple RunWith Statements in jUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431427/multiple-runwith-statements-in-junit)