# How to mock helper methods used in service class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

How to mock helper methods used in service class. I tried to search but couldn't find, can you guide me?How to mock helper methods used in service class. I tried to search but couldn't find, can you guide me?

Service class function:

```
@Autowired
private MongoOperationsUtil myUtil;
@Override
public MyResponse getUsage(MyData input)
{
    myUtil.checkExistance(input.getName);
    MyResponse resp = new MyResponse();
    resp.setUsage(usage);
    resp.setMetaInfo(input);
      
    return resp;
}

Helper class method - content:
@Autowired
private RedisUtil redisUtil;
///RedisUtil is a class I created for crud ops in redis
```

public void checkExistance(String name){

```
    boolean inputFound = redisUtil.isKeyExists(name);
    if (!inputFound) {
         redisUtil.insert(name);
        
    }
    else{
        redisUtil.update(name);
     }
```

}

this is test logic:
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ApiUsageServiceTests {
MongoOperationsUtil mongoUtilMock
=Mockito.mock(MongoOperationsUtil.class);

```
@Test
public void getUsageTest() throws Exception{
 System.out.println("Checking getUsage() from service layer");

doNothing().when(mongoUtilMock).checkExistance(anyString());
// when()
mongoUtilMock.checkExistance(Mockito.anyString());
verify(mongoUtilMock,  
times(1)).checkExistance(Mockito.anyString());
}}
```

Now I need to write testcase for getUsage, by mocking checkExistance helper method, so how to do that to ensure coverage of LOC?

Comment: This is going to depend on more details of `MongoOperationsUtil` than you've given us.

Comment: Mongo operations util is for crud operations and checking existence of data in db, basic operations

Comment: Don’t use field injection; it largely defeats the point of using DI. Whilst Mockito can be made to inject random private fields, it’s better in every way to use constructor injection; or setter injection at a stretch.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
private MongoOperationsUtil myUtil;
```

you use @Autowired in myUtil. So the object is injected into spring container.

If you want to mock it in your test case, try to use @MockBean for MongoOperationUtil field.

Then you could try

```
    Mockito.when(myUtil.checkExistance(XXX)).thenReturn(YYY);
```

Comment: I have added test class logic, can u tell what the issue could be, its is not ensuring coverage, all lines are not getting covered?

Comment: "all lines are not getting covered", do you mean all lines in MongoOperationsUtil not coverted?  Because you used Mock, it didn't really run the logic in your MongoOperationsUtil class.  Unit test should just test your Service class, if you want improve coverage, you may just write anther ut in MongoOperationsUtil.

Comment: all lines of the service layer method are not getting covered, I am not checking coverage of util claass here, just the service layermethod.

Comment: Looks like you use MockitoJUnitRunner which is specific for use with the Mockito test framework.  You may use SpringRunner and use MockBean in  MongoOperationsUtil  and Autowired for your service class. And the below thread may help you . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738078/whats-the-difference-between-runwithmockitojunitrunner-class-and-runwithsp/56745558

Comment: I used @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) as well, but does not help. dont know why its failing to show coverage?