# How to combine these two RunWith in Java JUnit?

Tags: java, junit, powermock

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Runwith(PowerMockRunner.class)

How can I merge these two annotation. As RunWith only supports single value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44575071

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this question is not detailed enough to give you any meaningful help. Please edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example for the issue, including sample input, preferred output, and code for what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If your are working with *JUnit 5* you can't use it since *PowerMock* doesn't [support it](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/830) yet.

With *JUnit 4* use `@Runwith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and  add `SpringRunner.class` using `@PowerMockRunnerDelegate` annotation. e.g.

```java
    import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner; 
    import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
    import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate;

    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest(LogHelper.class)
    @WebMvcTest(controllers = UserController.class)
    public class UserControllerTest {

        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Mock
        private UserService userService;

        @Test
        public void saveShouldReturnOK() {
            mockStatic(LogHelper.class);
            doNothing().when(LogHelper.info(anyString()));
            ....
        }
    }
```