# use 2 RunWith() together in junit

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit, robolectric

I use @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class) and I need to use @RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner::class)
, can I use together are in one class?

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner::class)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(application = AppControllerTest::class, sdk = [28])
open class TestMaster {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple RunWith Statements in jUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431427/multiple-runwith-statements-in-junit)

Comment: @EnzoMolion I need for RobolectricTestRunner and JUnitParamsRunner

Comment: The point is that you can't, because you can only have one `@RunWith` annotation.