# How to use multiple classes inside @RunWith()?

Tags: spring, java-8, integration-testing, junit4, spring-annotations

I am trying to run an integration test using junit4 for which I need to use @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) but I also need to use @RunWith(RunIfRunner.class) for implementing the solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/mjeanroy/junit-runif)

How to ensure the use of both on these? Or is there any other way to deal with this other than using @RunWith()?

Note: I need to use the solution mentioned in the link above(check here - [1](https://github.com/mjeanroy/junit-runif)).

Comment: You don't you can only have 1 runner. I believe there is a JUnit rule to mimic (Partially) the `@RunWith` so you could combine one with the other. Or ditch this approach and move to JUnit5 for which you can quite easy write conditional tests without the need for additional extensions.

Comment: The particular `Runner` implementation would have to support delegating to an arbitrary other `Runner`.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I can't switch to junit5 as RunIfRunner.class is implemented with junit4. Any idea how to implement something like this for my case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431427/multiple-runwith-statements-in-junit/24431738#24431738

Comment: @Holger how to implement that?

Comment: You don't need `RUnIfRunner` with JUnit5 as conditionally running tests is part of JUnit5. So yuou don\t need all the extra stuff as it is build into the framework!