# Junit4 how add multiple classes for @RunWith annotation

Tags: java, junit4

How can i add the multiple @RunWith or there are any other alternative available. I must use the Parameterized.class with other class which i cannnot exclude

```
@RunWith(ScenarioStepRunner.class)
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Test{


}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple RunWith Statements in jUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431427/multiple-runwith-statements-in-junit)